# D2007: Installed IDE Extensions - now one important component doesn't work

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

On my D2007 installation, I installed the [DDevExtension](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10), and also the IDEFixPack from the same site.

Unfortunately, now I have a component, [TmxSideBarPro](http://www.maxcomponents.net/index.php?id=13&page=0), that won't load into the IDE anymore. Any time I try, I get the following error in the IDE:

EPackageRegistrationException
Registration procedure, Mxtaskpanereg.Register in package c:!_cg2007\Packages\mxTaskPane_D11D.bpl raised exception class EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 20006A04 in module 'rtl100.bpl'. Read of address 9B8825DB.

I have tried uninstalling the extension above, and they report a successful uninstall, but I still get the error above when trying to install the component. The component vendor hasn't helped much, and I'm not sure they're in business anymore at this point. They did ask if I'd installed any special IDE tools, I explained my situation to them, but I never heard back from them anymore.

What can I do here to get this component working again? I'm willing to reinstall D2007, but I've also got D2009 installed, and I've read that you shouldn't install an older version after a new version.

Also, if there's a different forum category this should be in, please let me know.

Comment: If this happened when you installed Andreas's plugins, I'd report it to him and see if he can help out with fixing it.

Comment: I've contacted him via a comment on his site, which is the only way I can see to contact him.

Comment: You can register at www.delphipraxis.net and contact him via private mail. His user name is "jbg".

Answer (score 0):

Is there something loading that mxTaskPane_D11D?  TO find out rename mxTaskPane_D11D to mxTaskPane_D11D!.!bpl  (extra characters). Now something ELSE will fail to load. Now unregister that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have uninstalled both DDevExtensions and IDEFixPack, for the right version?
If so your Delphi should be as it was before.
They don't do any permanent modification IIRC.

Are you sure nothing else changed? Did you recompile the mx package by any chance?
I've found Andreas' tools of very good quality and I would probably look elsewhere 1st...

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I uninstalled for the right version, and I've done it several times to be sure.  Nothing else changed as far as I know.  I have tried to recompile several times - the recompile works, but when I try to install the design-time package I always get the AV error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that component, but if you have the source code for it, try recompiling the package.  I had to recompile several component packages when migrating from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2007.  Many of the packages were Delphi 5 packages.

Comment: I've tried the recompile, but when I go to install the design-time package in the IDE, I still get the same AV error.

Comment: Delphi might be attempting to load a different copy of the bpl than the one you are building.  Make sure there are no copies of mxTaskPane_D11D.bpl on you system anywhere.  I would just rename every instance of this bpl you find.  Then compile it and see what happens.